# How to create a web.config for a non ASP.net executable in IIS?

Tags: iis, rust, iis-8

I need to host an API I wrote in Rust with IIS, I have never used IIS. Everyone else I have spoke to has been using .NET and found it to be pretty much just plug and play.

Any time I create a web.config file based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/web-config?view=aspnetcore-7.0 I get a 500.19 internal server error. If I do not create a web.config I presume it isn't even trying to do anything and I get 403.14 Forbidden.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\MyApp.exe"
                  stdoutLogEnabled="false"
                  stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"
                  hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

The above was basically what I used that gave me the 500.19 error, and within IIS it complains that it cannot read the configuration file at all which is rather annoying considering I got this config off of microsoft's documentation.

Comment: I do not know how did you create your Rust API but I would suggest for you the https://actix.rs/ framework. You can run the `cargo run` command and then go to your localhost. Honestly, configuring IIS involves a lot of steps and complexity.

Comment: 500.19 is not a surprise if you never install ASP.NET Core module. But "everyone else" you spoke to is probably not very familiar with IIS, as HttpPlatformHandler is there for non-ASP.NET stacks for more than a decade, https://halfblood.pro/the-rough-history-of-iis-httpplatformhandler/ There isn't plug and play for Rust, as far as I know, but you can learn from the Java/Python/Node.js/Go examples which show the common pattern on what's required.

Comment: could you please share which framework you have used to develop the api, you could try to use the HttpPlatformHandler to host the rust api on iis as lex li said or you can use proxy

Comment: I should've updated this, but I got it working yesterday. It was an issue in finding the correct documentation, everything was either telling me to use .NET, reverse proxy or fast CGI. As @JalpaPanchal and LexLi said, HttpPlatformHandler was the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HttpPlatformHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/windows-server-azure-pack/mt125371(v=technet.10)) was the answer, thank you Microsoft for making that so hard to find. You do not have to use reverse proxy, FastCGI, switch to .NET or anything like that.

Comment: There is no need to blame Microsoft and its documentation. Searching on the internet has its own difficulty.